# Reload previously unloaded content ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, reload

Not really sure how to begin thinking about solving this issue. Many searches for loading and unloading ajax just return results about how to unload before loading new stuff, not reload the previously unloaded content.

I have a web app that loads content into a target div, which contains links that would unload the first loaded content and then load in the new content into the same target div. What I would like to do is create a script that will change the `href` to reload the content that was previously unloaded.

To put this into perspective, I am building a portfolio that loads a portfolio full of project thumbs from the index. Clicking on a project thumb will unload the all thumbs and load the project details. I would like a back button that will link back to load the portfolio thumbs and then from there, clicking again will link back to the main index.

The structure is like this:

1. /index.php
2. /portfolio/index.php (list of thumbnails linking to each project)
3. /portfolio/project.php (gathers the relevant information about the project)

I need a button that:
isn't shown when at state 1
Links back to the index at state 2
And links back to the portfolio at state 3.

For the moment, I have this which partially works, but obviously relies on me typing in the specific pages to check. I'd like something that dynamically changes.

```
//If link containes project.php, show the back button, if not hide it.
        if(destination.indexOf('project.php')>=0){
            $('div.back-button').css({'display':'block'});
            $('a.back-button').attr('href', 'portfolio');
        }
        else if(destination.indexOf('portfolio')>=0){
            $('div.back-button').css({'display':'block'});
            $('a.back-button').attr('href', '/app');
        }
        else{
            $('div.back-button').css({'display':'none'});
        };
```

I'm guessing I need to create a variable somewhere that catches the content being loaded and becomes the location to return to. But how do I start the chain off when nothing is clicked and then delay the use of it until one more click later?

For example, when I click portfolio from the index, I want it to remember that 'portfolio' is loaded, but then only use that as a variable for the button location once I have then clicked on a project. Once project is loaded, the back button would then locate back to portfolio.

Any help on how to tackle this would be appreciated!

You can see how far I've got at http://joeallam.co.uk/app

Answer (score 0):

After you've loaded something you want to keep via AJAX, save the innerHTML of that element as a JavaScript variable. Then when someone presses BACK, just put the contents of that variable back into the same DIV that normally loads the AJAX content.

```
var saveThis;
saveThis = $('#ajaxTarget').html() //save
$('#ajaxTarget').html(saveThis) // load
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I've tried implementing it but with no success as yet due to the complexities of other parts to my setup. The theory seems to be correct though and will post when I get it working. I'm still open to other suggestions though if available.

Comment: You may also want to look into url hash techniques, allowing the browser itself to cache the response. http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2011/10/must-know-url-hashtechniques-for-ajax-applications/

Comment: I have already looked into using hashchange techniques, however for this particular purpose, it's not the right solution. I am building a web app that doesn't need to have the URL change as it will not be shareable links. Im building a tool for myself, using the web as my method rather than for distribution. Thanks for the link though!